# What is the difference between putc and ungetc?

Tags: c++, c, function

`int ungetc(int c, FILE *fp)` pushes the character c back into fp, and returns either c, or `EOF` for an error.

where as int `putc(int c, FILE *fp)` writes the character c into the file fp and returns the character written, or `EOF` for an error.

//These are the statements from K&R. I find myself confused, because `putc()` can be used after `getc` and can work as `ungetc`. So whats the use in specifically defining `ungetc()`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`putc` writes something to output, so it appears on the screen or in the file to which you've redirected output.

`ungetc` put something back into the *input* buffer, so the next time you call `getc` (or `fgetc`, etc.) that's what you'll get.

You normally use `putc` to write output. You normally use `ungetc` when you're reading input, and the only way you know you've reached the end of something is when you read a character that can't be part of the current "something". E.g., you're reading and converting an integer, you continue until you read something other than a digit -- then you `ungetc` that non-digit character to be processed as the next something coming from the stream.

Comment: thanx for such an explanatory answer..:)

Answer (score 2):

ungetc works with streams opened for read and doesn't modify the original file.  putc works on streams opened for write and actually writes the byte to the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you do `ungetc` on a stream `fp`, and then you do a `getc` again, you get back the same character you just put in. If you do `putc` the "stream moves on", and a subsequent `getc` will get whatever is after it, if there is anything... 
The `getc` and `ungetc` are used to "peek ahead" and put it back if there is some special case in handling characters e.g.

Comment: Just after putc if i do getc wont i get the same character which i just put in...cause it will be just where file pointer point to...isnt it?

Comment: yes, putc moves the file pointer to after that character, which is the output buffer, and indeed (as Jerry said) ungetc puts in back into an input buffer (they could be the same, which what I was assuming)

Comment: ya so the main difference is ungetc puts in input buffer whereas putc puts it in output buffer...

Comment: not only that, but ungetc also ensures that the file pointer stays at that place, while after putc it moves one along. The next putc will be put after this one (if you do nothing inbetween).