# confusion regrading ungetc function

Tags: c, input, scanf, ungetc

I am not understanding how this program works?

```
char c;
int i;
for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
{
     scanf("%c",&c);
     printf("%c",c);
     ungetc(c,stdin);
}
```

The output of the program is- character which is entered first time is printed 5 times.

```
a
aaaaa
```

According to SO post [What is the difference between putc and ungetc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079785/what-is-the-difference-between-putc-and-ungetc) `ungetc` puts something back into the input buffer.

So in this program during the first iteration `scanf()` accepts input from the keyboard and `printf()` displays it and then `ungetc()` pushes back the same character into the input buffer.

But during the second iteration no input is being accepted, so I am guessing `printf()` prints the character which was pushed into the input buffer by `ungetc()`.

Can someone explain in clear manner how exactly this program works?

Comment: I think the newline character that gets added when you press return is getting in the way.

Comment: You actually explained it pretty well, just remove "I am guessing". `scanf()` reads from the input buffer. `ungetc()` already put something there, so there's no need to wait for more input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ungetc) of `ungetc()`

> `ungetc()` pushes `c` back to stream, cast to unsigned char, where it is available for subsequent read operations.

So, basically, whatever `char` you enter for the first time, that is being read in `c` variable, and after printing, the same value is being pushed to the input buffer. Now, `scanf()` reads from the input buffer, so the value pushed by `ungetc()` is available for the next `scanf()` to read it. That is why, `scanf()` is no *asking* for *user input*.

Now, as the loop runs for 5 times, you'll encounter  5 `scanf()`s, all reading the first ever input data, and printing the same 5 times.

That said, always check the return value of `scanf()` to ensure it's success.

Comment: What if I declare char x='a' and put this in ungetc function `ungetc(x,stdin)` and place it in between `scanf` and `printf`. Should it display `a` 5 times?

Comment: @Ravi Why don't you try? :-)

Comment: Output is`raaaa` where `r` is the first character I entered

Comment: @Ravi And did you understand the o/p? The first iteration prints the scannned char, that is `r`, then , you're pusing `'a'`, so, for remaining 4 iteraion, it will _scan_ `'a'` from the buffer and print it.

Answer (score 3):

This is happening:

- Your input: `a\n`
- `scanf` read `a` leaving behind `\n`.
- `printf` print `a`.
- `ungetc` push back `a` to the input buffer and now the input is again `a\n`.
- Repeat this `5` times.